# I ran out of ideas for this nested for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, nested

So I am trying to practice Java. I am a beginner. 
I have this exercise which requires me to write a nested for loop.

**The results should be like:**

```
Enter the size:4
Triangle is:
1
22
333
4444

Enter the size:6
Triangle is:
1
22
333
4444
55555
666666
```

**Here's my code:**

```
public static void main(String arg[]){

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter the size:");
int size=scanner.nextInt();
System.out.println("Triangle is:");

//add your nested for loop logic here
//start
for(int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
{
    System.out.println(i);
    for(int j = 1; j < size; j++)
{

}
```

I am trying to wrap my head around it but I cannot seem to think of another way.
So what do I need to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
     for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
           System.out.print(i);
     }
     System.out.println();
 }
```

This will produce:

`Enter the size:
4
Triangle is:
1
22
333
4444`

The inner loop will print number `i`, `i` times as variable `j` runs from `1` to `i`. And then in next line we introduce a new line.

Answer (score 0):

There are just a couple things I'd like to mention in addition to what was already said.

1. You should try to line up in your mind what you're doing in your algorithm design before even trying to implement it into code. In this case, what do you actually have to do to make the triangle show up? Well first, you need to keep track of which line you're on, and then which row you're on in that line. The maximum number of lines is specified by the user in `size`, so you stop there. Then for each row, you're going to be printing a character, which also happens to be row-number. The maximum number of columns is the same as the row you're on, since it's supposed to be a triangle. So instead of stopping at `size` again, you want `row`. Since you're saying the printing is done before you even know which column you're on, this suggests you might not have fully designed your algorithm first "on paper."
2. It's best to try to name your variables after what they're actually pointing to, rather than just an arbitrary letter such as "i" or "j". It's often common to use these arbitrary variables when they're just to keeping track of how many iterations there are, but when you're referring to them in your loop it's good to have them reasonably named for readability. When you're just starting out, this is even more important so you can keep track of what you're actually doing! You might want to consider something like this:

   ```
   for (int row = 1; row <= size; row++)
   {
       for (column = 1; column <= row; column++)
       {
           System.out.print(row);
       }
       System.out.println();
   }
   ```

   This way you're also seeing right in the code that you're printing the line number as opposed to just some counter.
3. This is probably really nit-picky on my part, but text prompts usually always have input on the same line as the prompt, rather than being on the next line. So instead of using `println()`, you might be better off with `System.out.print("Enter the size:  ");` (Also notice the space after the colon).

Hope this helps!